# Request to add a tag info page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Most of the people ( especially [php](/questions/tagged/php) users) know of the tag [cv-pls](/questions/tagged/cv-pls). I got to know about  this tag from the starred conversation in  PHP chat room. So i don't think so it would be there forever. There was a link to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/1689430) which explained what it was created for?

This is a nice approach to keep the content of question relating to `php` clean on stack overflow, but for all the new people (like me ;) ) who would see this tag for the first time, will surely  try to look for it's wiki page on SO, which currently [doesn't exists](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cv-pls/info).

So, a request to create a tag wiki page/info page for this tag, as it would be appropriate to keep all the SO related info on SO itself, currently this info seems to be scattered (as in this case, a gist explains a functionality of a process on SO). We can atleast copy-paste the text from the gist to the tag wiki page.

Such kind of things will happen, and we can't stop it, but atleast minimize those, and keep SO environment clean and complete by itself.

#### One more suggestion

As this is not a compete tag by itself, it's something that got created from the php community on SO, got famous via chat, I suggest to create a separate feature that would support such kind of tags. I envisage, there would be more such tags coming in future.

-Thanks

Comment: See also [previous discussion about `cv-pls`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120186/135887) and how the PHP chat room uses it.  It's worth noting that [information about `cv-pls`](https://gist.github.com/1689430) is **constantly "stuck" at the top of the starred question list** in the PHP room.

Comment: I had gone through that discussion. But, my point here is to 'complete eradicate such kind of thing from SO', or 'include it in SO'. Take one of these steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this tag would not have any *actual questions* associated with it, there's no reason to create a tag wiki for it.

Additionally, giving it a wiki would probably encourage people to actually start *using* the tag, and that's not good either, as the tag is undoubtedly a meta tag, which is also a no-go on the site.

You should keep the gist pinned to the room, with descriptive text for the link indicating what those tags mean so people can use it as a reference.  A tag wiki is *not* the place for this reference.

Tag wikis are for *actual* tags on *actual* questions.

Comment: My **One more suggestion** part of the questions explains the same thing.

Comment: @mtk That's the thing, no such tags like that will be coming in the future as they'd all be meta tags.  Meta tags are not allowed on Stack Overflow.  If you have a feature request I'd separate it from this support request to create a tag wiki.

Comment: So, considering it as a feature request, what can be done for such tags ? Don't you think, the meta-tag explanation should be kept in the  same [so] or it's [metase] site, rather than pinning the gist to explain the stuff?

Comment: @mtk No, these types of tags **are not tags**.  They have no place on the site.  Repurposing tags for this purpose is an abuse of the tagging system.  My suggestion is to find a separate, new feature request that doesn't involve using an existing feature for a way that's already been decided is not correct.