# Disallow tag wiki creation if the tag does not exist

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

CasperOne's answer to [Request to add a tag info page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143790/request-to-add-a-tag-info-page) has reminded me of something I wanted to ask.

I recently [rejected an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/341344) to the tag wiki of [video-game](/questions/tagged/video-game). The tag didn't exist and it was a meta-tag anyway.

As there's no point creating tag wiki's for non-existent tags and it could lead to extra crap <sup>(technical term)</sup> coming into the system why not ban it altogether?

To quote from casperOne's answer, which gives a better description than "crap":

> Because this tag would not have any actual questions associated with
>   it, there's no reason to create a tag wiki for it.
>
> Additionally, giving it a wiki would probably encourage people to
>   actually start using the tag, and that's not good either, as the tag
>   is undoubtedly a meta tag, which is also a no-go on the site.

Comment: I would like to know, how such tags came into existence? Or have they been skipped from the moderation? Probably, this concern might have not been envisaged while creating them ;)

Comment: Tag wikis are *supposed* to be automatically rejected when the tag they were suggested on is destroyed. Apparently this bug *still* exists.

Comment: I wonder if the tag wiki actually sticks or just immediately gets orphaned. Tag wikis from deleted tags go to the orphanage. Either way you shouldn't be able to add/suggest them

Comment: @BenBrocka, it appears to be orphaned looking at the rejected edit.

Comment: Huh, you could theoretically get rep just by getting these approved then, then probably just immediately resubmit the same edit since it gets orphaned.

Comment: Anyone who actually bothers to do that probably deserves the rep...

Comment: Anyone who actually bothers to do that is going to incur the wrath of the New Tag Deletionist Cabal.  Seriously though, tags don't actually stop existing until a few *hours* after they've been removed from their last question.  I'm pretty sure that if we waited long enough, the wikis in the queue would disappear.  For better or worse, the new edit queue interface has done an amazing job at keeping the queue down to a reasonable size, so we're unlikely to see this in action.

Comment: Related: [The old behavior of orphaned tag wiki suggestions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121023/how-do-you-approve-reject-an-orphaned-suggested-edit-with-no-buttons)